# When pressing button and toggling a Bool var all of my Bool vars toggle?

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui, state

I have a form with several Boolean variables that change images on toggle, but when I click any of the buttons, all my variables change images?  I have pulled all of them into separate subviews with the same result.  Doesn't make any sense to me.  Any help would be appreciated.  Probably something simple I'm overlooking, but I'll be damned if I can see it.

Here is the code.

```
@State var total: String = ""
@State var date: Date = Date()
@State var bathroom: Bool = false
@State var steps: Bool = false
@State var furniture: Bool = false
@State var travel: Bool = false
@State var woodFloor: Bool = false
@State var concreteFloor: Bool = false
@State var takeUp: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Job Info")
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            ) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    DatePicker("Date", selection: $date)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Total: $")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding(.trailing, 0)
                        TextField("", text: $total)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 20, alignment: .leading)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                }

                Section(header: Text("Addons")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Text("Bathroom")
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                self.bathroom.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: bathroom ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                           }
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Steps")
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                self.steps.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: steps ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                            }
                        }

                        HStack {
                            Text("Furniture")
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                self.furniture.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: furniture ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put all buttons in one row (`VStack` with `HStacks` creates one view, so one row), and `Form` (being a `List`) sends all actions whenever any button is clicked in a row (it is designed to have one active element in a row).

So the solution would be either to remove `VStack`

```
Section(header: Text("Addons")
    .font(.title3)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .padding(.bottom, 10)
) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {      // << this !!
        Spacer()
```

and let every `HStack` with button live in own row...

... or instead of buttons use `Image` with tap gesture, like

```
    HStack {
        Text("Steps")
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: steps ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
          .padding()
          .onTapGesture {
            self.steps.toggle()
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button inside a `Section` of `Form` the whole section will act as a button. So when you tap on it, all 3 button actions get executed.

instead, You can use `Image` with `.onTapGesture{}` modifier. In that way, you'll get what you want.

Sample code,

```
 Image(systemName: bathroom ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
   .foregroundColor(.blue)
   .onTapGesture {
      self.bathroom.toggle()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting the wrong thing from `Form`. `Form`s are not to make flexible lists with fancy stuff. If you want to be able to do anything you want and be able to customize your list at will, you should probably use `Grid`s and other normal components like `VStack`...

#### How to use Form and what to expect:

The easiest way to see what you can do or not do with `Form`s without working around the limitations, is to go to the settings on your iPhone and see how different part of the settings are made. You can achieve almost all those stuff **very** easily without much work. However, if you want something even a little bit different than what you see in the settings, then you probably need a workaround to implement that in your app because `Form`s are not flexible.
Example of what you can do with `Form`s, taken from the settings:
[image]

For clarification, i am not saying you can't achieve what you want using forms. I'm saying thats most likely not a good idea to try to force forms to be something that they are not supposed to be.

#### The Answer:

So what should you do now? You should probably replace your button with `Toggle`s so you get something similar to what you see in the settings.
[Other people have already said how to fix your current problem, so i'll just say the better way]
Consider using something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var date = Date()
    @State var total = ""
    @State var bathroom = false
    @State var steps = false
    @State var furniture = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // DELETE this if the view before this view
                         // already has a navigation view
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Job Info")) {
                    DatePicker("Date", selection: $date)
                    NavigationLink.init(
                        destination: FormTextFieldView(name: "Total $", value: $total),
                        label: {
                            Text("Total")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("$ " + total).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        })
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Addons")) {
                    Toggle("Bathroom", isOn: $bathroom)
                    Toggle("Steps", isOn: $steps)
                    Toggle("Furniture", isOn: $furniture)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Form", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}

struct FormTextFieldView: View {
    
    let name: String
    @Binding var value: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField(name, text: $value)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(name)
    }
}
```

#### Why to use this?

First, because it is built with **No Effort**. You barely need to use any modifiers. So simple!
Second, this will work well on *Any* apple device. When you use modifiers, specially setting a frame for the view, you'll need to consider what will happen if you use e.g. an iPad. You don't need to worry about that when you are using this approach.